# Setting and accessing Vue.prototype values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set a property globally, using `Vue.prototype`, but I'm having a bit of trouble

I have the following:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
    Vue.prototype.$teamsContext = true;
});


new Vue({
    el: '#overview',
    components: {
        Index
    },
    data: {
       // add attributes here
    },
});
```

I'm guessing this prevents me from using `Vue.prototype` inside the `getContext` call as `$teamsContext` is never set.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

EDIT::

I have added some more code.

In the `Index` component, inside the `created()` method, I'm doing a `console.log("CONTEXT", this.$teamsContext)`, which returns `CONTEXT undefined`

Comment: Where in your project structure do these lines reside?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't set? Are you seeing any errors? Is `getContent` calling your function? Put in some logging or a `debugger` statement to check.

Comment: @YomS. I have updated my question with a bit more code

Comment: @skirtle I have updated my question with a bit more code

Comment: Is `getContext` asynchronous? I would assume so if it takes a callback. You don't seem to be waiting for it to finish before kicking off your Vue application. That `created` hook will be called before you've set the value. Try putting in console logging in both places and check the order they happen.

Comment: It would seem that the `created()` method is called first, so, yeah it won't be set.... Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting problem.

Assuming `getContext` is asynchronous, my approach would be to load(mount) the app after `getContext` is ready.

Here's the implementation:

```
// main.js

import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app;

const onResourceLoaded = () => {
  app.$mount("#app");
};

const littlePlugin = {
  async install(Vue, options) {
    // Add here your async action
    const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    const parsedResp = await resp.json();

    // Add global property after the action is ready
    Vue.prototype.$name = parsedResp.title;

    // Mount the app
    onResourceLoaded();
  }
};

Vue.use(littlePlugin);

app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-7pyc6) is a live example.

#### NB

Because your asynchronous action might be done through a `callback`, you might need to wrap this into a promise:

```
const promisifyContext = () => new Promise(res => {
  microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
    resolve(context);
  });
});

// Inside `install` function
const context = await promisifyContext();
Vue.prototype.$teamsContext = context;

onResourceLoaded();
```